# Activate pointClickCallback in a time series to capture peaks and valleys

Tags: r, time-series, r-dygraphs

I am trying to select manually the peaks and valleys from a noisy sinusoidal signal within  a time series which is  displayed on a dygraph using R. I create a simple example below.

```
x=seq(0.1,10,by=0.01)
y=sin(x)
ts = data.frame(x,y)
dygraph(ts)
dyCallbacks(ts,pointClickCallback = function(e, pt){alert(this.getValue(pt.idx,1))})
```

However I am not able to record the clicks on the peaks and valleys with the dycallbacks call. The error message I get is:

> The arguments for JS() must be a character vector

Comment: `pointClickCallback`  should be a character vector

Comment: also a better solution would be to use `shiny` in order to. put all the points coordinates in a `csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is rising because you're giving the correct params to [`dyCallbacks(dygraph, pointClickCallback)`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dygraphs/versions/1.1.1.6/topics/dyCallbacks) which takes :

- `dygraph` : Dygraph to add callbacks to.
- `pointClickCallback` : A (JS) function to call when a data point is clicked. and the point that was clicked. i.e a character vector to be later on passed to `JS()` function.
- .... other callbacks.

So the correct code is :

```
dy <- dygraph(ts)
dyCallbacks(dy ,pointClickCallback = "function(e, pt){alert(this.getValue(pt.idx,1))}")
```

### Writing it to a file:

I think using `shiny` is definitely justifiable in this case as we're going to have easy access to base `R` functions:

```r
library(shiny)
# generating the user interface of the webpage
ui = fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    # tells shiny to add a dygraph output
    dygraphOutput("dygraph"),
    # tells shiny to a <br/> element return to new line in html
    br(),
    # tells shiny to add a text output in here we will show the coordinates of the point that has been clicked.
    textOutput("clicked", inline = TRUE)
  )
)
server = function(input, output) {
  # generating the sinusoïdal time series
  x=seq(0.1,10,by=0.01)
  y=sin(x)
  ts = data.frame(x,y)

  # outputting the dygraph
  output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({
    dygraph(ts) 
  })

  # printing coordinates in HTML
  output$clicked <- renderText({
   # output text only if a point has been clicked
   if(!is.null(input$dygraph_click$x_closest_point)) paste0("x = ", input$dygraph_click$x_closest_point, ", y = ", input$dygraph_click$y_closest_point)
  })

  #printing the coordinates of the clicked point in console
  printPoint <- reactive({
    print(c(x=input$dygraph_click$x_closest_point, y=input$dygraph_click$y_closest_point))
  })

  # whenever the dygraph is clicked the expression {} is evaluated
  # basically printing the coordinates in console and adding them to the peaks csv file
  observeEvent(input$dygraph_click,{
      printPoint()
      write.table(data.frame(x=input$dygraph_click$x_closest_point, y=input$dygraph_click$y_closest_point), "peaks.csv", sep = ",", col.names = !file.exists("peaks.csv"), row.names=F, append = T)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### Non-shiny solution using only callbacks and js

```
js <- "function(e,vs){
    if(!window.points) {
        window.points = ['x,y'];
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerHTML = 'Download Data';
        button.style = 'position: absolute; top: 15px;left:40px;';
        button.id = 'download';
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        document.body.appendChild(button);

        $('#download').click( function(){
            var csvContent = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + window.points.join('\\n');
            var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
            window.open(encodedUri);
        });
    }
}"
x=seq(0.1,10,by=0.01)
y=sin(x)
ts = data.frame(x,y)
dy <- dygraph(ts)
dyCallbacks(dy, drawCallback=js, pointClickCallback = "function(e, pt){window.points.push(this.getValue(pt.idx,0)+\",\"+this.getValue(pt.idx,1))}")
```

#### Output in `peaks.csv`

```
"x","y"
5.05,-0.943548668635907
5.05,-0.943548668635907
4.26,-0.899405409685178
```

Comment: Thanks. That certainly displays the value. Is it possible to capture all those in a file.

Comment: @user2004198 I added some explanations

Comment: While this is an excellent solution, is there a possibility of improving upon the non-shiny solution that you first offered to save to a file.

Comment: plain js can't write to files as a security measure on way would be to use the clipboard but any accidental ctrl+c could erase the data.

Comment: @user2004198 check the new edit. the `drawCallback` creates a button and once this button is clicked you can download your csv

Comment: would it be possible to provide the R code for the clipboard solution. No worry about Ctrl_c because I have the time series file archived. The current solution is fine with R Studio but not as an R script.

Comment: @user2004198 is this solution not working. it took me at least an hour to come up with it

Comment: There is a lot of work that you have gone to in your solution. The app does not work outside of R Studio and the latest R Studio creates occasional freezing with the latest Ubuntu 20.04.1 but it is not critical...just nice to have.

Comment: if you run it in an R console it will work flawlessly.

Comment: @user2004198 have you tried running it in R console ?